# Networkx: Get the summation of all node shortest path length as one aggregated value

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I'm a beginner at using NetworkX and I'm trying to find a way, to sum up, all the shortest path values for one node to other nodes of the graph as one aggregated value, for instance, the length of node ***B is 6 as in the bellow result of the code***. I got the shortest path between all pairs of nodes in the graph, but I need help in adding the length of each node as one value as mentioned above. Any help would be really appreciated. Below is the code for calculating the shortest path length. I edited the question so that to get the **node_density** value to the individual node as well as shown in the code below.

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_nodes_from(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
>>> G.add_edges_from([("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("C", "D"), ("D", "E")])
>>> sp = nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G)
>>> sp["A"]["E"]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
>>> spl = nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G)
>>> spl["A"]["E"]
4
>>> dc = 1
>>> for node1 in spl:
...   for node2 in spl[node1]:
...     print("Length between", node1, "and", node2, "is", spl[node1][node2])
...     node_density = spl[node1][node2] - dc
        if(node_density <= 0):
            node_density = 1
        else:
            node_density = 0
Length between B and B is 0
Length between B and A is 1
Length between B and E is 3
Length between B and C is 1
Length between B and D is 2
Length between A and B is 1
... (and so on!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `spl` is a dict of dicts holding the lengths for each node to every other node you can loop through the outer dict and sum the length values to each of the other nodes.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
G.add_edges_from([("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("C", "D"), ("D", "E")])
sp = dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G))
sp["A"]["E"]
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
spl = dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G))
# spl["A"]["E"]


# sum the lengths to individual nodes
new_dict = {node1: sum([length for length in spl[node1].values()]) for node1 in spl.keys()}
# print the lengths
for node,length in new_dict.items():
    print('The sum of lengths from node {} to all other nodes is {}.'.format(node,length))

#The sum of lengths from node A to all other nodes is 10.
#The sum of lengths from node B to all other nodes is 7.
#The sum of lengths from node C to all other nodes is 6.
#The sum of lengths from node D to all other nodes is 7.
#The sum of lengths from node E to all other nodes is 10.
```

Comment: thanks a lot dear, it worked for me real perfect. what if i want to subtract a value between any pairs of length value and the sum the length of these modified length to individual nodes, for instance, node_density = spl[node1][node2] - dc  if(node_density<= 0):
            node_density = 1
        else:
            node_density = 0  how to print these nodes_density to each individual node instead of only the length?